# How pass data from my views to my controllers

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

i'm trying to pull data from my backend, in my angular controllers, but first i need pass the a variable from my views to my controllers.

I already setup the route, the partial, the controller and the api in the backend, so the only think that is missing is the variable.

This is how i'm trying to do:

```
<a href="/admin/#/eventos/editar/" + {{event.id} + ""  class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Editar</a>
```

Or

```
<a href="/admin/#/eventos/editar/{{event.id}"  class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Editar</a>
```

But is not working. I'm coming from EJS, and that's how i learned...

Comment: Any variable on the $scope is available on the view, bind using $scope.variable in the view {{variable}}

Comment: @AnandaFerrari I think missing parenthesis is the reason its not working..it needs to be like this.. _a href="/admin/#/eventos/editar/{{event.id}}"_ and you can use _a ng-href="/admin/#/eventos/editar/{{event.id}}"_ too..

Comment: there is multiple events Dave, i want click in one and pull them using params..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to use the [`ng-href`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref) directive

re-write to the following

```
<a ng-href="/admin/#/eventos/editar/{{event.id}}"  class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Editar</a>
```

Edited

Comment: @viraj thanks I didn't catch the closing curly brace